# Is there something like '5s' for replacing words (instead of letters)?

Tags: insert-mode

Given the following line

```
this is a testing line
```

When my cursor is on "a" and then I type `2s`, it becomes

```
this is testing line
```

My cursor is on "t" of testing, and I am in insert mode.

Is there something like this that replaces words instead of letters and then puts you in insert mode?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for `ciw` (change inner word) or `ce` (change to end of word). Please clarify as I am not sure exactly what you are asking for. I would suggest you run `vimturor` and start reading the manuals. I suggest start reading at `:h usr_02.txt` and continue though each chapter. Then use `:h quickref` if you need to find a motion/topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking whether there's a way to eliminate *n* words and drop into insert mode to conveniently replace them with something else, yes there is, with a few variations.

With your cursor on the `a`, you could do `c2w` (or `2cw`) to remove `a testing` and drop into insert mode with your cursor before the space preceding `line`. This operation can also span multiple lines, so if you had your cursor on the `a` in

```
this is a testing line
and this is another one
```

and typed `5cw` it would join the lines and drop you into insert mode with your cursor placed between `is` and `is`

```
this is  is another one
```

The `w` movement in this context encompasses characters from the cursor to the end of a word, so if you start from within a word, the beginning of the word will be unaffected. For example, with the cursor on the `x`

```
flexible stuff bends
```

typing `c2w` eliminates `xible stuff` and puts you insert mode with the cursor after the `fle` in `fle bends`. You could also have used `e` instead of `w` in all the previous examples and it would behave the same.

If you wanted to operate on the entire word instead, you could use `caw` or `ciw`. In the previous example, typing `2caw` removes `flexible stuff` (including the following space) and puts you in insert mode with your cursor right before `bends`. `ciw` acts a bit differently, and it's easier to try it out and get a sense for it than for me to try to describe it.